# SQLite Exception - CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am getting the exception - android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Main Activity code -

```
Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery("Select * from Vocabwords", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String word = cursor.getString(1);
String meaning = cursor.getString(2);
TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv1.setText(word);
tv2.setText(meaning);
cursor.close();
db.close();
```

SQLiteHelper code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {   
    db.execSQL("create table Vocabwords (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Word text, Meaning text)");
    insertNewEntry(db, "Diabolic","Evil");
    insertNewEntry(db,"Concede","Agree to an argument after declaring it incorrect in past");
}

public void insertNewEntry( SQLiteDatabase db,String word, String meaning){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Word", word);
    contentValues.put("Meaning", meaning);
    db.insert("Vocabwords", null, contentValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the table is empty and you are trying to get the column values of the 1st row.
This is why you should check first with the method `moveToFirst()` if the cursor returned any rows:

```
Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery("Select * from Vocabwords", null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String word = cursor.getString(1);
    String meaning = cursor.getString(2);
    TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv1.setText(word);
    tv2.setText(meaning);
}

cursor.close();
db.close();
```

Comment: But why is the table empty as I have written the code to populate it. Is there any mistake in my query?

Comment: @AdarshPrajapati this is a different requirement for which you should post a new question where you explain what the problem is by providing all the relevant code.